# Table show in List in MVC 4

Tags: list, model-view-controller

```
 public class PersonsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Persons/
    PersonContext PC = new PersonContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Person> P = PC.person.ToList();

        return View(P);
    }
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my controller class and I want to display my table data in List Format. How can I do this?

MY model class is **Person**
and Context class is **PersonContext**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what properties you have in your 'Person' model. 
But you can use such sample in your view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var person in Model)
    {
      <li>paste here primitives of your `Person` model</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: what we actually do with .Add() method in mvc? PC.person.Add(person1);   PC is the object of my context class, and person is the property of my model class Person, but what is meaning of this method Add();

Comment: As you are using list, Add() method just adds person to collection. But if I were you I would use another viewmodel  even similar to person. Business logics has to be separate from view.